# ImageView loop animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I want to create 20 different animation on the screen
(the appearance and disappearance of image) with different times of the repetition these animation.

My code for one image

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{

        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(148, 0, 17, 18)];
        _imageVIew.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png»];
        [self.view addSubview: _imageView];
        [_star setAlpha:0];
        [_star setAlpha:1];

} completion:nil];
```

If I use this code the devices heats up. How to reduce the load on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example you want to create a animation with these images

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load images
    NSArray *imageNames = @[@"win_1.png", @"win_2.png", @"win_3.png", @"win_4.png",
                        @"win_5.png", @"win_6.png", @"win_7.png", @"win_8.png",
                        @"win_9.png", @"win_10.png", @"win_11.png", @"win_12.png",
                        @"win_13.png", @"win_14.png", @"win_15.png", @"win_16.png"];

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    // Normal Animation
    UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 95, 86, 193)];
    animationImageView.animationImages = images;
    animationImageView.animationDuration = 0.5;

    [self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
    [animationImageView startAnimating];
}
```

You can see more here http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you want :(